# ExceptionHandler, got java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve method parameter at index 0?

Tags: java, spring, exception, handler

I've a problem with the ExceptionHandler of Java Spring. I have a my Exception called EntityNotFoundException, and I want call ExceptionHandler method from REST Controller when exception is thrown.

This is my REST Controller method code:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity insertTicket(@Valid @RequestBody Ticket ticket, @AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal) throws EntityNotFoundException {
    ticket.setCreationTimestamp(Instant.now());
    ticket.setSource(TicketSource.CLIENT);
    ticket.setCurrentTicketStatus(TicketStatus.VALIDATION);
    User customer = userController.findUserByUsername(principal.getName());
    ticket.setCustomer(customer);
    try {
        ticket.setAttachments(savedFiles(
                ticket.getAttachments(),
                ticket.getCustomer().getUsername()
        ));
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        return CommonResponseEntity.NotFoundResponseEntity("ENTITY_NOT_FOUND");
    }
    ticketController.insertTicket(ticket);

    mailSenderController.sendMail(customer.getEmail(), "TICKET_OPENED");

    return CommonResponseEntity.CreatedResponseEntity("CREATED");
}
```

This is my Exception Handler code:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ControllerAdvice
@RestControllerAdvice
public class InterceptedResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends 
   ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    BindingResult bindingResult = ex.getBindingResult();

    List<MethodArgumentFieldError> methodArgumentFieldErrors = bindingResult
            .getFieldErrors()
            .stream()
            .map(fieldError -> new MethodArgumentFieldError(fieldError.getField(), fieldError.getCode(), fieldError.getRejectedValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<MethodArgumentGlobalError> methodArgumentGlobalErrors = bindingResult
            .getGlobalErrors()
            .stream()
            .map(globalError -> new MethodArgumentGlobalError(globalError.getCode()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    MethodArgumentError methodArgumentError = new MethodArgumentError(methodArgumentFieldErrors, methodArgumentGlobalErrors);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(methodArgumentError, HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
}

@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMissingServletRequestParameter(MissingServletRequestParameterException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    MissingParameterError missingParameterError = new MissingParameterError(ex.getParameterName(), ex.getMessage());

    return new ResponseEntity<>(missingParameterError, HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
}



@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleNotFound(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {

    System.out.println("inside!");

    if( ex instanceof DataIntegrityViolationException){
        System.out.println("Data integrity violation");
        String constraintViolationErrors = ex.getMessage();
        String msgErr = (constraintViolationErrors.substring(constraintViolationErrors.indexOf("=") + 1));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(msgErr, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    if(ex instanceof UsernameNotFoundException) {
        String msgErr = ex.getMessage();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(msgErr, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }


    if (ex instanceof NotFoundEntityException || ex instanceof EntityNotFoundException || ex instanceof NoSuchElementException){
        //return CommonResponseEntity.NotFoundResponseEntity(ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("inside the handler!");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(),HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    if(ex instanceof  UpdateException){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }

    return null;
}





@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MethodArgumentError {
    private List<MethodArgumentFieldError> fieldErrors;
    private List<MethodArgumentGlobalError> globalErrors;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MethodArgumentFieldError {
    private String field;
    private String code;
    private Object rejectedValue;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MethodArgumentGlobalError {
    private String code;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MissingParameterError {
    private String parameterName;
    private String message;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ConstraintViolationError {
    private String invalidValue;
    private String message;
}
```

}

I don't know why, when I get a DataIntegrityViolationException the ExceptionHandler is called, instead when I get an EntitynotFoundException I get this message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve method parameter at index 0 in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.isssr.ticketing_system.rest.TicketRest.insertTicket(com.isssr.ticketing_system.entity.Ticket,java.security.Principal) throws com.isssr.ticketing_system.exception.EntityNotFoundException: No suitable resolver for argument 0 of type 'com.isssr.ticketing_system.entity.Ticket'
```

What's the problem??

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I suspect it might be because the exception you are seeing is being thrown before the controller's method is being executed. That is, the @ControllerAdvice is not applicable because it is not technically a `@Controller` throwing the exception. Rather the root cause is `java.lang.IllegalStateException`, which is perhaps being thrown before the method is actually called. Can you verify whether the method is even being "entered" when the problem occurs?

Comment: Yes, ticketController is called; I got the stacktrace with exception and with the correct message, the problem is that ExceptionHandler is not invoked so Exception is not handled. I can't understand why..

Comment: Precisely, I got this message:
"No suitable resolver for argument 0 of type 'com.isssr.ticketing_system.entity.Ticket"
Ticket is the first argument of my RestController method, but I don't understand how this is correlated with ExceptionHandler..It shouldn't treat with Rest arguments

Answer (score 0):

I saw other strage things; I get this message:

Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.isssr.ticketing_system.rest.TicketRest.insertTicket(com.isssr.ticketing_system.entity.Ticket,java.security.Principal) throws com.isssr.ticketing_system.exception.EntityNotFoundException

So it seems that Spring is trying to invoke another method instead of method of my ExceptionHandler.
How is possibile this?